# SSL certificate install on hosting, generating key

Tags: ssl, private-key

I have SSL certificate, which i upload on my hosting. I need to generate private key, how i can generate it without ssh access.
Thanks.

Comment: Voting to move to SuperUser (not a question about programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generate a private key from a certificate (that's the point).

If you already have your certificate, you must have generated a certificate request (CSR) (or perhaps its in-browser equivalent) and generated a private key at that time. This is the file you want, since other re-generated keys won't match the public key in the certificate you now have.

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands provided in the instructions for the tool you are using, but on your local machine. For example, if you are using OpenSSL on your hosting server, generate your private key file using your local command prompt, and upload that through the tools provided by your provider.

Comment: I not using OpenSSL certificate was buyed comodo.com

Comment: If it's your certificate, you should have the private key. If you lost that, you need to get a new certificate.